# Proof that a circle is not homeomorph to an 8-figure.

Tags: general-topology

I know that in homeomorphisms if the domain is connected then the counterdomain have to be also connected.

My idea is taking off a point from the circle and also taking the autointersection point from the 8-figure and then showing that there can't be an homeomorphism, since the 8-figure became not connected although the circle became a line and is still connected.

But I'm having some problems formalizing this, specially because I can't proof that taking a point from each set doesn't change the homeomorph relation.

Thanks!

Comment: Proceed by contradiction, and then the point on the circle corresponding to the junction point $p_0$ on the figure-8 is just $f(p_0)$ where $f$ is the alleged homeomorphism.

Comment: Removing a point $x$ from the space $X$ while also removing the corresponding point $h(x)$ from $Y$, where $h:X\to Y$ is the homeomorphism, does not change the homeomorphism relation, in other words $h:X\setminus\{x\} \to Y\setminus\{h(x)\}$ is still a homeomorphism. That's because, given any set $A\subset X$, the restriction $h|_A:A\to h(A)$ is a continuous bijection whose inverse is continuous too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fact: if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism, and $p \in X$, then $X \setminus \{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $Y \setminus \{f(p)\}$, and the restricted $f$ is the homeomorphism. The proof is obvious, as $f^{-1}$ is continuous from $Y$ to $X$ and its restriction to $Y \setminus \{f(p)\}$ is the inverse as well of $f|_{X \setminus \{p\}}$, and restrictions of continuous maps are continuous.

Now suppose a homeomorphism $f : E \rightarrow S^1$ exists, where $E$ is the figure eight.

Let $p$ be the intersection point of $E$. Then $E \setminus \{p\}$ is also homeomorphic to $S^1 \setminus \{f(p)\}$. But this is a contradiction, as the left set is disconnected and the right hand set is always connected, regardless of $f(p)$ (the circle is homogeneous and leaving out a point leaves an open interval). So no homeomorphism can exist.

Comment: sorry for taking so long to validate. I'm a noob here

Comment: @Alnitak it's alright. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the fundamental group, $\pi_1(S^1)$ is $Z$ and $\pi_1(eight figure)$ is the free group generated by two elements.